# Populate tkinter optionmenu using a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list that I want to use to populate an option menu in tkinter.
I have searched far and wide and cannot find a solution that works... any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class TestGUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.pack()
        self.mylist = ['test','test2','test3']
        self.emailDropDown= OptionMenu(root,self.mylist)
        self.emailDropDown.pack()

root = Tk()
gui = TestGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Every single example for option menus shows how to do this. You’re just passing the arguments wrong. If you want to pass them by position rather than by name, the list of options comes third, not second.

Comment: Do not import tkinter and ttk with both `*` and `tk/ttk`. The recommended method of importing is to use `import tkinter as ttk` and `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`. You should remove the other imports that use `*`.

Comment: @mike-SMT thanks for the comment, I did as you instructed and am now getting an error that says "NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
"

Comment: @MattG31 that is because you will need to add `tk.` as a suffix when adding a widget. Examples: `tk.Frame()`, `tk.Entry()`, `tk.Button()` and so on for each widget. The reason we do this is to keep the name space cleaner and to prevent accidentally overriding imported methods.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameters to an `OptionMenu` are not parent and options list, they’re parent, variable, and options list.

So, if you want to pass the arguments by position instead of by name, you need to pass your option list as the third one, not the second one.

See the [Tkinter book chapter on `OptionMenu`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as ttk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class TestGUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.pack()

        self.mylist = ['test','test2','test3']
        variable = StringVar()
        variable.set(self.mylist[0]) # default value
        self.w = OptionMenu(*(root, variable) + tuple(self.mylist))
        self.w.pack()



root = Tk()
gui = TestGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This works, however, the first list options disappears when you select it.. Still trying to find an answer to this